# How to get Json variable with $ symbol

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've been pulling my hair to get the `$type` variable.

jsonTxt.json

```
{
  "$type": "Things.YourThings.YourThingName, Things",
  "Name": "Doe"      
}
```

I tried to get the variable as a `string`, but with no success. I just get `null`.

Here is what I do:

```
public class CustomName
{

  [JsonProperty("$type")]
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then,

```
var customName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomName>(jsonText);
```

In actual fact, I just want to extract the type which is just the name `YourThingName`.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why I hate web service APIs that use inheritance in their response models and expose them as JSON. It's forcing service consumers to use the same serializer the service provider is using or to resort to ugly work-arounds like you have to now.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
var customName = new CustomName()
{
    Name = obj["Name"].ToString(),
    Type = obj["$type"].ToString()
};
```

Then to get just the `YourThingName` you can either use a Regex or just `String.Split`:

```
string name = Regex.Match(customName.Type, @"(?:\.)(\w*)(?:,)").Groups[1].ToString();
```

Or

```
string name = customName.Type.Split(',')[0].Split('.')[2];
```

You must do your boundary checks before accessing the different arrays or you'll end up with `IndexOutOfRange` exceptions.

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yU1PQ8)

Comment: I want to extract it as part of CustomName object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While it works for this particular case, but I must say this object is part of a bigger json tree. or to be specific, it is a variable to some object down the tree. That means I'll have to extract each variable manually. I'll try to edit the question when I get a chance.

Comment: To save my hair (LoL!), I've decided to use your `Regex.Match` with @Abbondanza's answer to extract the type as when needed. I'm not conversant with `regular expression`, but I see your `Regex.Match` works even when the `Namespace` become longer. Care to shed the light in this particular implementation?

Comment: @rm it finds a series of word characters between a `.` (period) and a `,` (comma) and extracts that.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to replace all occurences of `"$type"` with something like just `"type"`.

```
jsonText.Replace("\"$type\"", "\"type\"");
```

With...

```
public class CustomName
{
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...deserialization will work as expected:

```
var customName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomName>(jsonText);
var type = customName.Type;
```

Comment: seems I'll just have to combine your answer with @Nasreddine's. 1 question: any reason you are not using `.Replace("$type", "type")`?

Comment: You're right, that doesn't make much sense. Fixed it. But you should keep the escaped quotes `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

Json.Net provides a [`MetadataPropertyHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MetadataPropertyHandling.htm) setting which controls how it handles `$type`, `$ref` and `$id` metadata properties in the JSON.  By default it will consume these, meaning they are invisible to your classes.  However, if you set this setting to `Ignore`, then Json.Net will not process metadata properties at all, allowing you to handle them normally.  You don't need to resort to manipulating the JSON string manually beforehand.

```
string json = @"
{
  ""$type"": ""Things.YourThings.YourThingName, Things"",
  ""Name"": ""Doe""      
}";

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore
};

CustomName cn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomName>(json, settings);

Console.WriteLine("Type: " + cn.Type);    // Things.YourThings.YourThingName, Things
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + cn.Name);    // Doe
```

From there you can extract the short type name like this:

```
int i = cn.Type.LastIndexOf(", ");
int j = cn.Type.LastIndexOf(".", i);
string shortTypeName = cn.Type.Substring(j + 1, i - j - 1);

Console.WriteLine(shortTypeName);    // YourThingName
```

Comment: thx! very helpful, I don’t know why your answer is not set as best

Answer (score 0):

There is another (stupid) solution to this problem. Create the same type as described in the `$type` property and deserialize to it:

```
// Put this in a library project called "Things"
namespace Things.YourThings
{
     public class YourThingName
     {
         public string Name { get; set; }
     }
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
var customName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Things.YourThings.YourThingName>(jsonText);
var type = customName.GetType().Name;
```